# Open email for outlook from website

Tags: jquery, html, email, web, outlook

I was wondering if there was some sort of API that can load up a send email window in the outlook desktop application from a specified email on a webpage, I know for STEAM (Gaming application) you can specify actions based on a URL and it will open said function in the desktop application itself.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe there is. You can use a `mailto:` in a link, but that will be opened in the user's default email client. You cannot specifically say 'Open this in X program'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
window.location.href = "mailto:address@mail.com?body=mail+body";
```

Comment: exactly what I needed! Thank you!